# Odoo purchase costs from SQL tables

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I was trying to get the cost prices of some products, via SQL.

On the product tab I can see the cost, depending if it is average, FIFO, or standard.   I need to calculate the average cost, based on purchases, and obtain a cost history.

Can you tell me which tables contain the product cost price information?.

Comment: It is nearly impossible for us to be able to help you with how the question is currently presented. We need an example of your database schema looks like, what fields you might need, or even an example data set to help us understand. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and consider reposting, or editing your question.

Comment: This question is for odoo specialists. They know from experience that tables (out of almost 500) contain product cost information. The question is not for SQl queries.

Comment: You have an SQL tag on your question, and also you indicate you are trying to do something via SQL. Please only tag things relevant to your question.